# C++ std::string* s; Memory reclaimed?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, heap-memory, stack-memory

Given a function foo with a statement in it:

```
void foo() {
  std::string * s;
}
```

Is memory reclaimed after this function returns?

I am assuming yes because this pointer isn't pointing to anything but some people are saying no - that it is a dangling pointer.

Comment: Why are you creating pointers to strings anyway?  Are you familiar with RAII and how `std::string` manages its memory?

Answer (score 10):

`std::string* s` is just an uninitialized pointer to a string. The pointer will be destroyed when function foo returns (because the pointer itself is a local variable allocated on the stack). No `std::string` was ever created, hence you won't have any memory leak.

If you say

```
void foo() {
    std::string * s = new std::string;
}
```

Then you will have memory leak

Comment: Thanks! this confirms my thoughts about this simple situation.

Comment: *"just an uninitialized pointer to a string which will be destroyed"* -- This sentence is a bit ambiguous.  What will be destroyed?  The pointer?  Or the string that's not there?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: How does one destroy that which does not exist?

Comment: @EdS. The answer did not clearly state that the string did not exist.  Those were my words.

Comment: *"std::string* s is just an uninitialized pointer to a string."* - Seems clear.  If the OP doesn't understand the difference between initialized and uninitialized variables then he should take a step back away from pointers for the moment.  Also *"No std::string was ever created, hence you won't have any memory leak."*

Comment: @EdS. As you have over 50000 rep, the fact that it's clear to you seems irrelevant. And that last quote is an addition from Rob, it was not in the original answer.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: ...not an entirely unfair response.

Answer (score 1):

This code is typical when people learn about strings a-la C, and then start using C++ through C idioms.

C++ classes (in particular standard library classes) treat objects as *values*, and manage themselves the memory they need.

`std::string`, in this sense is not different from an `int`. If you need a "text container", just declare an std::string (not `std::string*`) and initialize it accordingly (uninitialized std::strings are empty by definition - and default constructor) than use it to form expression using method, operators and  related functions like you will do with other simple types.

std::string* itself is a symptom of a bad designed environment.

Explicit dynamic memory in C++ is typically used in two situation:

- You don't know at compile time the size of an object (typical with unknown size arrays, like C strings are)
- You don't know at compile time the runtime-type of an object (since its class will be decided on execution, based on some other input)

Now, std:string manage itself the first point, and does not support the second (it has no virtual methods), so allocating it dynamically adds no value: it just adds all the complication to manage yourself the memory to contain the string object that is itself a manager of other memory to contain its actual text.

Answer (score 0):

This code just creates a pointer to somewhere in memory, which contains string value and it points to somewhere which has been allocated before and it does not allocate new string.
it just allocate a memory for pointer value and after function return it's no more valid...

Comment: what punctuation marks are you talking about he's right the code just creates a pointer to somewhere in memory but he's wrong in that there is nothing allocating memory yet so it's technically not a dangling pointer because the pointer hasn't been assigned to anything yet.

Comment: @thang: It's a lack of punctuation marks, look at the original post.